# Wordpress fetch thumbnail and number of comments

Tags: php, wordpress

for the moment I use this code, it display the post title and the category,for the last 5 post. But I also want to show the thumbnail, the number of comments and a little part of the post (maybe the first 200 words)

```
<?php $posts = get_posts( "numberposts=5" ); ?>
<?php if( $posts ) : ?>
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>


<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p class="postmetadata"><?php _e( 'Posted in' ); ?> <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a featured image for the post you can then use the post thumbnail. You can see the options for images in the codex here but you can get the [post thumbnail](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) with something like

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'aligncenter')); ?>
```

Comment number details can be seen [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number) but it'd be something like

```
<?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?>
```

Excerpt length can be set in the functions.php of your theme. More details at the [the_excerpt](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) codex page but something like

`function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
    }
    add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );`

Comment: I tryed <?php comments_number(); ?> and it works but <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> still don't display anything.

Comment: You need to set a feature image to make that work. Look in the lower right hand corner of the post. There are also [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-post-thumbnail/) that will do it automatically with the first image in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Also if I add this `<?php the_content(); ?>` it shows the full post content with the thumbnail included. I just want the first 200 words of the post, how to do it?